# Is taken in into idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> Much later, he was eventually found by a Shinra agent, lying on the
> ground nearly dead in a secluded desert area in Nevada and **taken in**
> **into** a secret sacred headquarters in Roppongi, Tokyo, Japan.

I rarely see this phrase being used like this. I am wondering how grammatical and idiomatic this is. I understand this phrase to mean "accepted into" "let in into" followed by any location.

Comment: I think your cited use is a clumsy mash-up of two separate lexical items. Specifically, ***to take in*** = *to receive as a guest or lodger, to give shelter to* AS WELL AS the more "literal" sense ***taken / escorted/ carried into** [some location envisaged as a "container"]*. Effectively, he was "taken **in**" by an agent who "took him **into**" the HQ building.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment on your earlier question, you do not need both _in_ and _into_.

Comment: There’s a reason you rarely see this. It’s ungrammatical and clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Much later, he was eventually found by a Shinra agent, lying on the ground nearly dead in a secluded desert area in Nevada and taken in into a secret sacred headquarters in Roppongi, Tokyo, Japan.

As Kate has commented, we do not need both *in* and *into*.

From the context, the verb *take* takes the following definition.

> take verb (MOVE)

> A1 [ T ]

> to move something or someone from one place to another

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take)

The example is messy and has a *misplaced-modifier* problem.  Minimising changes to your original, I suggest

> Much later, lying on the ground nearly dead in a secluded desert area in Nevada, he was found by a Shinra agent and taken into a secret sacred headquarters in Roppongi, Tokyo, Japan.